# How to modify my git workflow now that I created github pages?

Tags: git, github, github-pages

I have a local repository on which I work on a daily basis. Typically, after a day's work, I commit locally and I push everything to a github repo by doing:

```
git add --all
git status // to check which changes are to be commited 
git commit -m "Some changes I've made"
git push origin master
```

Recently I've created a github page for my online repository, by clicking away through the online creation tool. Now I have a beautiful page for my project, and also a new branch (called gh-pages) on my online repo (but --so far-- not on my local repo, of course).

My question is: if I wanted to edit this page locally in my computer and keep both repos synced (the local and the github one), how do I do? How should I modify my git workflow?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Shouldn't this be the same as with any branch? You git pull remote branchname (so git pull origin gh-pages); and work with that.

Comment: "Typically, after a day's work, I commit locally and I push everything to a github repo..." As an aside, it is generally a good idea to commit very frequently with Git, usually *much* more often than once per day. Try to get in the habit of committing whenever you've made a set of cohesive changes instead of whenever the clock says you can go home from the office. (You can rearrange and squash commits locally before pushing if you want, but that's not necessary.)

Comment: I do Chris, thanks for the suggestion. "After a day's work" is just a way to go easy on the reader, as the details on the frequency of my commits does not change the content of my question. Thanks again.

Comment: Teknophilia: It's probably the case, but as I've never worked with branches (I'm a noob to git) I was looking for some help on it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just switch back and forth between `master`, etc. and `gh-pages` with `git checkout`. More details below.

Your original workflow (from above):

```
git add --all
git status // to check which changes are to be commited 
git commit -m "Some changes I've made"
git push origin master
```

Now when you want to work on your GH-pages:

```
git fetch origin    # Only needed first time
git checkout gh-pages
# Make changes to your GH-pages files (your master branch files won't be available w/o switching back to master)
git add .    # or specific specific files to add
git commit -m "Commit message for GH-pages"
git push origin gh-pages
```

When you want to go back to working on the master, develop, etc. branch project, just check it out:

```
git checkout master
```

This info can sort of be found at the bottom of https://help.github.com/articles/creating-pages-with-the-automatic-generator/.

The process is slightly more complex when the creating gh-pages orphan branch manually: https://help.github.com/articles/creating-project-pages-manually/

Of course, if you are not the only one working on the repo or are doing so from multiple computers, be sure to `fetch`/`merge` or `pull` when needed.